# How to pass parameter as column name in stored procedure in my example

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE PROCEDURE ProcedureName1 
    @columnsname varchar(50), 
    @columnsvalue varchar(50) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    with cet as   
    ( 
        Select  ID,
                names,
                Null As address,
                work,
                note
        From    Tabl1
        Where   @columnsname Like @columnsvalue
        Union All
        Select  t2.ID,
                t2.name,
                t2.address,
                Null,
                Null As tt
        From    Tabl2 As t2
        Left Join Tabl1 As t1
                On t2.ID = t1.ID
        Where   @columnsname Like @columnsvalue 
    )  
    Select  *
    From    cet
    Order By id,
            note Desc,
            cet.address  
END GO
```

Comment: I *really* hope you don't actually write your procedures like that.  It's an unreadable mess.  On that note, you forgot to ask a question...

Comment: Assuming you want to randomly check any column against a value you can't do this without dynamic sql. And using dynamic sql for this is highly prone to sql injection.

Comment: 1) Column and Table names are of type "sysname". 2) You cannot pass a variable where a column name or table name is required. 3) If you really need something like this, Dynamic SQL is the only way to go. 4) You should probably not even try something like this... push back and re-examine your requirements, this is just not a great idea. Bad performance, seriously security vulnerabilities.

Comment: I dont understand what is it you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to use dynamic sql for something like this. It would be a good idea to whitelist the value of `@columnsname` against `sys.columns` or `information_schema.columns` as well.

Use `sp_executesql` to continue to keep `@columnsvalue` as parameter, and not concatenate it to the SQL you will be executing.

```
create procedure ProcedureName1 (
   @columnsname sysname --varchar(50) 
 , @columnsvalue varchar(50)
) as
begin
declare @sql nvarchar(max), @column_name sysname;
/* make sure the @columnsname is a valid column name */
set @column_name = (
  select c.name
  from sys.columns c
  where c.object_id = object_id(N'Tabl1') 
    and c.name = @columnsname
  );
set @sql = 'with cte as (
    select 
        ID
      , names
      , null as address
      , work
      , note
    from Tabl1
    where '+@column_name+' like @columnsvalue
    union all
    select 
        t2.ID
      , t2.name
      , t2.address
      , null
      , null as tt
    from Tabl2 as t2
    left join Tabl1 as t1 on t2.ID = t1.ID
    where '+@column_name+' like @columnsvalue
    )
  select *
  from cet
  order by 
      id
    , note desc
    , address;'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@columnsvalue varchar(50)', @columnsvalue
end;
go
```

Reference:

- [The curse and blessings of dynamic SQL - Erland Sommarskog](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)
- [**`sp_executesql`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)